# Building out CRUD routes in node.js

Tags: mysql, ajax, json, node.js, express

My job involves a lot of relational database work across multiple projects. I'm trying to build out a set of routes that perform very flexible Create, Retrieve, Update, and Delete queries. My goal is to make these reusable over multiple projects, so I'm trying to avoid hardcoding as much as possible.

I'm using the latest versions of Express and MySQL 2 (very open to changing the DB module, but it seems to work fine). I'm keeping my app.js clean, it just calls routes, the view engine, and starts the server. I have a file in my routes folder called connect.js (following a naming convention we were using in LAMPstack), and this is where I intend to route all of the CRUD queries. It looks like this:

```html
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql2');

var connectionpool = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'roster',
    pool   : {maxConnections: 50, maxIdleTime: 30}
});

// CRUD
router.post('/create', function(req, res){
 
 var into = req.body.into;
 var string = req.body.set;
 var set = JSON.parse(string);

 var query = 'INSERT INTO ?? SET ?';

 console.log(query);
 
 connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
            if(err){
                console.error('CONNECTION error: ', err);
                res.statusCode = 503;
                res.send({
                    result: 'error',
                    err: err.code
                });
            } else {
   connection.query(query, [into, set],

    function(err, rows){
     if (err) console.error(err);
     res.send(rows);
    }
   );
   connection.release();
  }
 });
});

router.post('/retrieve', function(req, res){

 var select = req.body.select;
 var from = req.body.from;
 var string = req.body.where;
 var where = JSON.parse(string);

 var query = 'SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE ?';

 console.log(query);
 
 connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
  console.log('enters connection function');
        if(err){
            console.error('CONNECTION error: ', err);
            res.statusCode = 503;
            res.send({
                result: 'error',
                err: err.code
            });
        } else {
   connection.query(query, [select, from, where],
    function(err, rows){
     if (err) console.error(err);
     res.send(rows);
    }
   );
   connection.release();
  }
 });
});


router.post('/update', function(req, res){

 var update = req.body.update;
 var string1 = req.body.set;
 var set = JSON.parse(string1);
 var string2 = req.body.where;
 var where = JSON.parse(string2);

 var query = 'UPDATE ?? SET ? WHERE ?';

 console.log(query);

 connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
            if(err){
                console.error('CONNECTION error: ', err);
                res.statusCode = 503;
                res.send({
                    result: 'error',
                    err: err.code
                });
            } else {
   connection.query(query, [update, set, where],

    function(err, rows){
     if (err) console.error(err);
     res.send(rows);
    }
   );
   connection.release();
  }
 });
});

router.post('/delete', function(req, res){

 var from = req.body.from;
 var string = req.body.where;
 var where = JSON.parse(string);

 var query = 'DELETE FROM ?? WHERE ?';

 console.log(query);

 connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
            if(err){
                console.error('CONNECTION error: ', err);
                res.statusCode = 503;
                res.send({
                    result: 'error',
                    err: err.code
                });
            } else {
   connection.query(query, [from, where],

    function(err, rows){
     if (err) console.error(err);
     res.send();
    }
   );
   connection.release();
  }
 });

module.exports = router;
```

So that seems pretty straightforward. I'm using ajax to pass json objects to be used in the queries. An example would be:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var where = JSON.stringify({
  school_id: '517',
  school_grade: '6'
 });

 $.post('retrieve', {
   select: '*',
   from: 'student',
   where: where
  }).done(function(data){
   console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Some issues I have run into are passing JSON objects through the routes. It seems I have to stringify the object for it to post, and then parse it before passing it into the query. Is there a better way to do this?

I'm open to completely scrapping what I have and starting over.

Comment: You can use `res.json` instead of `res.send`. Also, if you set the correct content type on the GET/POST request - you can automate it (look into how $.post works). Moreover, you should automate releasing the connection (a disposer pattern) so you won't have a chance of dangling connections.

Comment: As a side note, look into REST conventions for your routes.  For example, your SELECT queries should map to HTTP GETs, not POSTS. Your CREATE should be a POST to /resource-name (e.g. create a new student record with POST /students).  Finally, I recognize that you're parameterizing your queries, but it looks *really* open to abuse the way you have it anyway. Anyone with a little knowledge of your data model could do a lot of damage.

Comment: @Benjamin you just made things like a million times easier for me (not just with this).

Comment: @Paul Thanks! I definitely need to brush up on that. Are there any measures I could take to secure the queries without sacrificing the parameters? Only authenticated users should be able to access these routes, and that's handled in a completely different place. What else can I do to lock them down? That's actually pretty important for us.

Comment: @user3630824 a common pattern is to use an ORM layer (e.g. sequelize) to limit things can be changed in the query.  But if you want to do it yourself, a better pattern than what you have would be to at least lock down what table is being modified and then do some kind of validation on the rest.

Comment: @Paul Thanks! I'll definitely keep working on it. My main goals for tomorrow morning are to look up REST conventions and ORM layers. Would you say this is a good start/approach to working with relational databases within the node.js framework? If there's something about my entire approach to this that could be improved I'd really like to start with that and build from there. I'm coming from a background of calling similar predefined PDO functions using AJAX, but I do realize that node.js is a completely different environment than working in a LAMP stack. I appreciate all your help so far.

Comment: I think once you add in REST and an ORM you'll see your style flex to match those conventions.  Both are less about node.js in particular, and more about a style of API-driven project organization.